# 'login' is not defined error happens in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I made frontend app in React.js.
I wrote codes in App.js of frontend like

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect, Component, View } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Routes from '../src/components/Routes';
import TopNavigation from './components/topNavigation';
import SideNavigation from './components/sideNavigation';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import './index.css';
import Router from './Router';

const App = () => {
  const [user, setLogin] = useState(null)
  const [report, setReport] = useState(null)
  useEffect(()=>{
  login().then(user => setLogin(user))
}, [])
  useEffect(()=>{
  getReport().then(report => setReport(report))
}, [])
return <div>
  {user != null? <p>name: {user.name}</p>:<button>Login</button>}
</div>
}

export default App;
```

I wrote in this code `login().then(user => setLogin(user))` whether user already logined or not.
Login system was made in Django,so I want to use it.I think React has login method but I really cannot understand what is wrong.How should I fix this?

Comment: `login` function is not defined anywhere, hence the error "login is not defined"...

Answer (score 0):

I can see nowhere `login` is defined in your code. If you've written `login` on other files, you should import it.

Actually, I cannot understand what you mean by this - "I think React has login method but ...". React doesn't support any predefined login method.

You should define login method yourself something like this.

```js
const API_URL = 'some url';
const login = async (body) => {
  const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/login`, body);
  return response.json();
};

const App = () => {
  const [user, setLogin] = useState(null);
  const [report, setReport] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    login({
      email: 'email@some.com',
      password: 'some password'
    }).then((user) => setLogin(user));
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    getReport().then((report) => setReport(report));
  }, []);
};
```